# Dash DataTable individual highlight using style_data_conditionals works unusual

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, plotly-dash

I'm working on a Project using Python3, Flask and Dash.
I'm visualizing a CSV Table using the `DataTable()` from `dash_table` and want to highlight some specific cells.

Accordistrong textng the documentation of table styling, this can be done by using the `style_data_conditional` attribute inside of the DataTable definition ([reference](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/style)).

My CSV table looks like this:

```
testclient, 0.40, 0.48, False, False, False, 0.14, True, True, 0.0, 2
raspberrypi, 0.20, 0.21, False, True, False, 0.18, True, False, 0.0, 3
```

When trying to access the first column, all style changes are working.

```
[...]
style_data_conditional=[
    {
        'if': {
            'column_id': 'hostname',
            'filter_query': '{hostname} eq "testclient"'
        },
        'color': 'green',
    }
],
[...]
```

But when trying to access any other row column like "ftp" or "http", it won't work and even if I use the `debug=True` parameter at the `app.run(...)` function call, I get no error output.

```
[...]
style_data_conditional=[
    {
        'if': {
            'column_id': 'ftp',
            'filter_query': '{ftp} eq "True"'
        },
        'color': 'green',
    }
],
[...]
```

There's an order of "style" attributes inside of the `DataTable` ...

> 1. style_data_conditional
> 2. style_data
> 3. style_filter_conditional
> 4. style_filter
> 5. style_header_conditional
> 6. style_header
> 7. style_cell_conditional
> 8. style_cell

... but as you can see, the given style attribute is the first mentioned in the listing.

The table is defined like this:

```
content = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    [...]
```

Do you have any clue, why the DataTable is behaving that strange just by changing the `column_id`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't provide column headers with your csv example, I can only assume that *ftp* and *http* refer to boolean columns?

The support for boolean-type columns in Dash DataTables seems to be anywhere between limited and non-existent. `filter_query` expressions don't seem to work with boolean values. The [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference) doesn't even mention a boolean data type for columns:

> columns (dict; optional):
>
> - *type* (a value equal to: 'any', 'numeric', 'text', 'datetime'; optional): The data-type of the column's data.

I worked around this by setting the data type for all boolean columns to `str` *in my dataframe*:

```
for col, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
    if dtype == 'bool':
        df[col] = df[col].astype('str')
```

Then, conditional styling works as expected:

```
DataTable(
    [...],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'hostname',
                'filter_query': '{hostname} eq "testclient"'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'green',
        },
        {
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'ftp',
                'filter_query': '{ftp} eq "True"'
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'green',
        }
    ]
)
```

[image: conditional cell styling for Dash DataTable]